# customtkinter images in IDLE

Tags: python, image, customtkinter

I want to display an image on a button in `ctk`, however I can't get the code to open the image.

Here is the part where its having issues:

```
img = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open("C:/Documents/a/cloud.png"))
```

and here is where I call it:

```
label_weather = ctk.CTkButton(tabView.tab("Map"), text ="Currently cloudy",image=img,compound="left",command=label_weather)

label_weather.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
```

[the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jcAI.png)

I put the code and the image in the same file and I tried calling getting it to work by putting it down differently such as:

```
img = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open("C:/a/cloud.png"))

img = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open("Documents/a/cloud.png"))

img = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open("a/cloud.png"))

img = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open("C:/a/cloud.png"))
```

The folder where I'm trying to get it:

[image: the folder where im trying to get it]

Comment: Welcome. Please edit your post so as to share all [code, data and error tracebacks as **text, not images**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code is due to the path of the image to open.

All the paths you tried above are wrong because the Documents folder isn't stored directly in C:/
The full path to the Documents folder is `C:/Users/[your username]/Documents`.

You should try to replace the path in your code by: `C:/Users/[your username]/Documents/a/cloud.png` (and replace [your username] by your username in windows).